# State updating only after second onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm building a React Native app which renders a flatlist of groups. By pressing on one group, you get to see all the individual items nested within.

I'm using the following [this navigation library](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) and I'm passing props as such:

```
const navigateToDetails = useCallback(() => {
    Navigation.push(props.componentId, {
      component: {
        name: pagesNames.DETAILS,
        passProps: {
          groupId: selectedGroup,
        },
      },
    });
  });
```

All of this is within a functional component which has a couple more relevant things, to begin with we have the state and function that gets us selectedGroup:

const [selectedGroup, setSelectedGroup] = useState(Number);

```
function handleTouch(value) {
    setSelectedGroup(value);
    console.log('value: ' + value);
    navigateToDetails(value);
  }
```

**value** is taken from an item in a `Flatlist` which gets its data from [this fake API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums).

Value is retrieved from the list in this fashion:

```
<FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.card, { width: windowWidth - 30 }]}
            onPress={() => handleTouch(item.id)}>
           {misc components}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
```

**Expected Behaviour**

I'm expecting that when I tap an item from the list, it'd navigate to the Details page and populate it with its data. However this does not happen. Upon logging out value and selectedGroup, I find that value is always logged out correctly but selectedGroup is always first logged out as 0.
Only after a second press does it show the expected id and populate the Details page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redirected before state is set. initialize selectedGroup with null/undefined/0

try navigating in useEffect

```js
function handleTouch(value) {
    setSelectedGroup(value);
    console.log('value: ' + value);
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (selectedGroup) {
   navigateToDetails(selectedGroup)
  }

}, [selectedGroup, navigateToDetails])
```